# How to find private ip address on google cloud?

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform, ip

I have the option to get new public IP address on Google Cloud. But I didn't get private IP address to configure on Apache virtual host. How to find internal (private) IP address on Google Cloud?

Comment: Grammar, readability, capitalisation.

Comment: Thanks for the  English grammar, please update tech answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've not had any experience with Google Cloud platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn your private IP following these steps:

1. At the Google Cloud Platform click on Products & Services which is the icon with the four bars at the top left hand corner.
2. On the menu go to the Compute section and hover on Compute Engine and then click on VM Instances to view all your instances.
3. Search for your VM instance in the list and look in the Internal IP column for it to learn your VM Instance internal IP

You can also open your [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/starting-cloud-shell) and run this command:

```
gcloud compute instances describe <your-instance-name> --zone <your-instance-zone>|grep -i networkIP
```

### -------